# Concatenation of Lambda functions in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

I got the following code:

```
two_to_one = lambda g: (lambda y: g(y, y))
one_to_two = lambda f: (lambda x, y: f(x)+f(y))
h=one_to_two(two_to_one (lambda x, y: x*y))
print (h(3, 2)) #prints 13
```

However, I got stuck on how to debug the whole thing, I didn't quite manage to catch why it prints 13. This is just a brainteaser question, but I would love to get some insight on how to tackle it the right way!

Comment: You should try using a debugger and stepping through the code.

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand this, you have to analyze what it does:

- `two_to_one = lambda g: (lambda y: g(y, y))` is a decorator function which turns a function `g`, which takes two parameters into one which takes one parameter. The argument you give to this parameter is used twice.
- `one_to_two = lambda f: (lambda x, y: f(x)+f(y))` is a decorator function which turns a function `g`, which takes one parameter into one which takes two parameters. The arguments you give to these parameters are used each for a function call, the results are added.
- `lambda x, y: x*y` takes two parameters and returns their product.

Having analyzed this, let's look what happens:

- `two_to_one(lambda x, y: x*y)` gives a function which returns the square of the given value. Why? Because it is essentially `lambda x: x*x`.
- `h`, which is defined as above, is equivalent to `lambda x, y: x*x + y*y`.
- `h(3, 2)` thus returns 3 * 3 + 2 * 2 = 9 * 4 = 13.